# How to pass a method into a Function?

Tags: javascript

*Forgive me if the title is wrong/improper.*

**How can the following code be expressed in one line?**

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();
```

I'm looking for something like this: `Date(getFullYear())`

Comment: `var d = new Date().getFullYear();`?

Comment: @Andrew wow .. brain fart.. Can you delete this question please.

Comment: Can't you? There are no up-voted answers, yet.

Comment: @go____yourself though he *can*, I'm sure he won't. You should have tried this

Comment: No I can't it wont let me..

Comment: As @AmitJoki alludes to, it's really not appropriate for me to delete this like that. I can close it, and it'll be deleted eventually, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var n = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Date().getFullYear();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCP2w/1/)